# DOMParse innerHTML does not show first element if it is a script

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, domparser

I am using DOMParser to parse some content do some changes to it and convert it back to HTML. Surprisingly, innerHTML does not show the first element if it is a script tag. So, something like

```
var x = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<script>var x;</script>', 'text/html').body.innerHTML
```

results in `x` being an empty string.

See more detailed example here:
https://jsbin.com/jotukabace/edit?html,js,output

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It went in the `<head>`, not the `<body>`, which is where you’d find the script in the DOM if you opened a document containing only that HTML in a browser.

```js
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<script>var x;<\/script>', 'text/html');
console.log(doc.head.innerHTML);
```

(Before `<head>` is present, anything that can go in `<head>` does. [Relevant part of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode))